# C# Excel to OleDB without sheet name

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to add Excel data to database. I can do it with sheet name, but it limits user to use app, so I want that user can upload Excel file with any sheet name.

This is my code:

```
public static DataSet ReadExcelFile(string sheetName, string path)
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string Import_FileName = path;
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);

        if (fileExtension == ".xls")
           conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'";

        if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
           conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";

        using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
        {
             comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]";
             comm.Connection = conn;

             using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
             {
                 da.SelectCommand = comm;
                 da.Fill(ds, "Table");
                 return ds;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

How can I load Excel data into the database with any sheet name?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To me your request is unclear, Excel files always have sheets, what do you want to do? Take data just from the first sheet? Iterate every sheet?

Comment: I mean think that i have two excel files, one's of them has sheet name as sheet1 onether one has sheet name sheet2, in my code, i can add both xml data to database

Comment: comm.CommandText = "Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]"; sheetName can be any string

Comment: So basically you want to take the first sheet of the excel?

Answer (score 0):

In my case use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace to read sheetname form Excel file first.

```
Excel.Application MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;

Excel.Workbooks MyBooks = MyApp.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook MyBook = MyBooks.Open(excelFilePath);
Excel.Worksheet XlsDb = MyBook.Sheets[1] as Excel.Worksheet;

string sheetName = XlsDb.Name;
DataSet excelDataSet = ReadExcelFile(sheetname, path);
```

after you've got sheetname, don't forget to close Excel that you've opened by code above (You can see that they will have Excel task in taskmanager if you don't close it. Even your program is already closed).

```
MyBook.Close(0);
MyApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(XlsDb);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyBooks);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(MyApp);
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```